# Globalization or Localization for my XNA app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, xna, globalization

I'm writing XNA game and want my game to support 5 different languages and be visible in all the respective markets where users speak those 5 languages. 
  So what I have:

- graphics with text translated into all 5 languages - buttons, logos
  and so on
- metadata translated into all 5 languages

So what are my next steps? I've seen examples for Silverlight, but I develop in XNA.  Basically, what is the difference between globalization and localization? Which one should I use? Will I have to produce 5 different .xap builds or one universal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Globalization is the combination of internationalization an localization;
- Internationalization - your application is able to support a range of languages and locales;
- Localization - your application is able to support specific language/locale;
- Language - is the code, ISO for portuguese is pt, for brazilian portuguese is pt_BR;
- Locale - Brazil. There are differences between Brazilian portuguese and Portugal Portuguese;

You can use the "Namespace: System.Globalization" it is supported in the XNA framework for xbox 360 and windows phone 7.0

Comment: thank you for reply:) can you pleas clarify if I should make 1 unversal .xap or App Hub expect me to provide 5 different .xaps?

Comment: The recommended is to submit a single app that supports multiples languages.

Comment: When submitting your app, the supported languages will be detected and you will be able to provide specific description, screen captures, keywords, ... for each language. But you can only give one single Application name for the App hub. So in case you want localized app title in the MarketPlace, you'll have to publish several .xap, changing the default language.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967550(v=vs.92).aspx Here Microsoft tells how to localize application titles. Maybe I'm wrong, but is it really necessary to give 5 different .xaps?

Comment: Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637522(v=VS.92).aspx - Microsoft recommends that you develop and submit a single application that supports multiple languages, instead of developing and submitting separate applications for each language type.

Comment: Ha yes, my mistake! Thanks for sharing that resource. I didn't know it was possible, I thought it used the Application Name (provided when submitting a xap) in the marketplace to display title to users, but it's for internal use only in the dashboard. So yes, you're right! It's possible to localize application titles also.